# Nano - File already being edited - How do I switch to the open file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nano

I have a tendency to miss-type while trying to Ctrl-X to exit nano.

Every now and then I'll try to re-open the file and get the Nano "File xxx is being edited". How do I switch back to the open file? And also, what am I miss-typing to cause this to happen?

Comment: You might be hitting ctrl-z and putting in the background (you'll see "[1]+ Stopped ..."). Try "jobs" and "fg".

Answer (score 34):

First check if there is a process editing the file.

`$> jobs`

You will get a list of background jobs, look for Stopped ones.

If there is and it's your editor, try re-attaching to it:

`$> fg <n>`

Else, if there is no running nano, make sure there is no lock-file.

`ls -A *.swp`

If there is, remove it.

`rm nnn.swp`

If you still have trouble editing the file, reboot and restart above.
Maybe there are more things to try, but that's all I can think of...

Answer (score 2):

nano creates a lock file once you try to edit the file, I would say just try to move it and it might work.